# Ubuntu only working with second monitor

Tags: installation, monitor, hp

I'm using the try ubuntu selection from my ubuntu cd.  For some reason, the screen on my laptop is completely black.  Only when I hook to my second monitor does ubuntu show up, and then, its only on the second monitor.  Any help?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to set up the monitor configuration using function keys. However sometimes the live version may not have all the drivers required (for example: for the special keys)